# RSA crypto between Node.js and webcrypto

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

I'm really stuck on this! What i'm trying to do:

- Generate a RSA keypair using ursa/webcrypto
- Send the public key as PEM over the wire
- Import the public key on the other end, and encrypt some text with it
- Send back the ciphertext and decrypt it on the other end using the private key

Now somehow I get either an undefined DOMException in the browser if I try to do the encryption part with ursa, or I get this error in Node.js when I do the encryption in the browser:

```
Missing error handler on `socket`.
Error: error:040A1079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error
    at Error (native)
    at Object.decrypt (/home/jeroen/projects/crypto-nodebrowser/node_modules/ursa/lib/ursa.js:358:33)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/jeroen/projects/crypto-nodebrowser/server.js:34:50)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Socket.onevent (/home/jeroen/projects/crypto-nodebrowser/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:330:8)
    at Socket.onpacket (/home/jeroen/projects/crypto-nodebrowser/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:290:12)
    at Client.ondecoded (/home/jeroen/projects/crypto-nodebrowser/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:193:14)
    at Decoder.Emitter.emit (/home/jeroen/projects/crypto-nodebrowser/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:134:20)
    at Decoder.add (/home/jeroen/projects/crypto-nodebrowser/node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js:247:12)
```

I made a minimal code example at https://github.com/jvanveen/crypto-nodebrowser that shows the issue. Any help on this is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally got it. Openssl has OAEP padding hardcoded using SHA1, so ursa's openssl bindings are not suitable if you want to use RSA-OAEP-256. I couldn't find a way to make this work with node-rsa, but Node-forge is quite straightforward here. Just use something like:

```js
var encrypted = publicKey.encrypt(bytes, 'RSA-OAEP', {
    md: forge.md.sha256.create()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to tell us both the code you are running and the browser it is running in?

Some browsers may only do RSA-OAEP with SHA-1 but from the brief description you have given it is having issues with the decryption. I think more details are needed.

Comment: Hi, I am testing with a recent Chromium version. When I run the server and open the page, the somewhat hackish testcases are executed. At this point the first testcase passes: it's able to generate a keypair on node.js, convert it to jwk, send the jwk to the browser, webcrypto is able to import the jwk and export the jwk back, the jwk is sent back to the server and the server confirms that the jwk/pem is still the same.

The second testcase fails. It first tests if the keys can be used to encrypt/decrypt locally, then sends the ciphertext to the server. On the server I get the oaep error...

Comment: Both NodeRSA and Ursa generate a similar error about OAEP padding:
Error: error:040A1079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error

Comment: The webcrypto imported key from ursa/nodersa has a slightly different moduluslength than a generated one:

keypair.private.algorithm.modulusLength => 2047
keypair.generated.privateKey.algorithm.modulusLength => 2048
keypair.generated.privateKey.algorithm.publicExponent  => [1, 0, 1]
keypair.private.algorithm.publicExponent  => [1, 0, 1]

Comment: Someone suggested that Node.js by default uses sha1 instead of sha256 hashing. I'm not sure if that is causing the problem here...

Comment: Just confirmed this by settings webcrypto to sha1! Wonder if I can change the Node.js side to use sha256.