# NodeJS - Decrypting with RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm using AES to encrypt data and RSA public key to encrypt the AES key used to encrypt data.

I have encrypted the AES key with RSA in Java using `RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING` and now I would want to decrypt that RSA encrypted key in NodeJS app. Is it possible to decrypt that AES key?

So basically I'm looking for `RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING` equivalent in NodeJS. (I did look at [Java's RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding equivalent in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834903/javas-rsa-ecb-oaepwithsha-256andmgf1padding-equivalent-in-node-js) but there isn't anything useful)

I looked at [NodeJS Decipher](https://nodejs.org/dist/v11.2.0/docs/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_decipher) and [crypto.privateDecrypt](https://nodejs.org/dist/v11.2.0/docs/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_privatedecrypt_privatekey_buffer) but it seems that there is no equivalent for `OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING` in NodeJS

Do I need to change `OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING` to something that else, that could be decrypted in NodeJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding` for Java side and `crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING` for NodeJS. This implementation is as secure as my original one and doesn't require any third party libraries.