# Read public key from ".cer" file for RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding in Node.js

Tags: node.js, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have `publicKey.cer` file with me and I want to encrypt some text using that certificate.

I need to use is `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding` algorithm.

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834903/javas-rsa-ecb-oaepwithsha-256andmgf1padding-equivalent-in-node-js) here suggested that we can use below code to encrypt.

I am using node-forge npm package. as it was suggested in above linked answer. Which outdated. So latest library suggestion is also welcome as I couldn't find any other way thus far.

But I am unable to figure out how can I use `publicKey` when I have `.cer` file with me. How can I convert my `.cer` file to this `publicKey` below. Tried many googling but unable to get this.

```
var encrypted = publicKey.encrypt(bytes, 'RSA-OAEP', {
  md: forge.md.sha256.create(),
  mgf1: {
    md: forge.md.sha256.create()
  }
});
```

Comment: What crypto libraries are you using? Also, what is contained in `publicKey.cer`? Filename extensions are not authoritative as to the contents, especially in the crypto world.

Comment: node-forge. updated question.

Comment: publicKey.cer file contains binary data.

Comment: What are you trying to exchange encrypted data with?  There are a lot of potential variations of OAEP.  Read the comments on the the answer you linked to...

Comment: I have same requirement as theirs. WithSHA-256 and MGF1Padding

Comment: I just need to encrypt some parameters which I need to append in url and on receiving end those will be decrypted.

Comment: If your .cer file contains a DER encoded certificate, you can import it with `pki.certificateFromAsn1(asn1.fromDer(<binary string>))`. The public key is provided by the `publicKey` property, s. [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge#x509) for details. You can then apply your code for the encryption with RSA/OAEP.

Comment: @Topaco. When I converted it to pem. It gave certificate property only.